# Number of labeled trees which have one vertex of degree 4

Tags: graph-theory

How many labeled trees which have one vertex of degree 4 can we have?

A tree with $10$ vertices has $9$ edges, so the sum of the degrees of the vertices is $2\cdot 9=18$. If there is one vertex of degree $4$, the sum of the degrees of the other $9$ vertices must be $14$. I don't know what to do next. Should I count all possible vertex degrees?

Comment: Is "$10$ vertices" just an example, and you need to solve it in general for $n\in\mathbb N$ vertices, or is the problem to count the number of such trees with exactly $n=10$  vertices? (All having at least one vertex of degree $4$.)

Comment: n = 10 vertices

Answer (score 1):

This is due to Clarke (1958). Let $C(n,k)$ denote the number of (labelled) trees $T_n$ in which a given vertex, say the $n$th, has degree $d_n=k$.

**Theorem (Clarke):** If $1 \leq k \leq n-1$, then $C(n,k)= {n-2 \choose {k-1}} (n-1)^{n-k-1}$

You can find the proof [here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Epak/hidden/papers/Moon-counting_labelled_trees.pdf) due to Moon. The idea is nicely described in the provided proof and I don't think that I could add much more value to it other than reformulating it.

For $k=4$ and $n=10$, we get
$$C(10,4)= {8 \choose 3} (9)^{5}=3306744$$